# Does pandas support read `set` paramater using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I save `set` parameter using to_csv.

`csv` file as below.

> 1,59,"set([17122, 196, 26405, 13032, 39657, 12427, 25133, 35951,
>   38928, 2       6088, 10258, 49235, 10326, 13176, 30450, 41787, 14084,
>   46149])",18,19.0,1       1,5.36363649368

Can I use `read_csv` and return a `set` type but `str`

```
users = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH + "users_match.csv", dtype={
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Your solution

```
users = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH + "users_match.csv", header = None)
```

will already return column 2 as a string as long as you have double quotes around `set([...])`.
Then use

```
users[2].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
```

to convert it back to `set`

Comment: Then I should use `df['xx'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))` to convert it

Answer (score 1):

To convert the DataFrame's `str` object (the string starting with the characters "set") into a built-in Python `set` object, here is one way:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('users_match.csv', header=None)
>>> type(df[2][0])
str
>>> df.set_value(0, 2, eval(df[2][0]))
>>> type(df[2][0])
set
```